# "all in one" - how else can this be said?

Tags: expression-choice

How else could this be said?

> Our package is *all in one*
>
> Our package is *all under one roof*

How many variations of this expression are there?

Comment: The expression is "All inclusive" or just "All in"

Comment: @mplungjan Surely there are other ways of meaning the same thing? such as "all under one roof"

Comment: Not if you are talking about a vacation package.

Comment: Hmm maybe i didn't explain my question very well. I'm basically after anything that refers to a collective being in one place.

Comment: *comprehensive*?

Comment: @DamkerngT. I need more of a phrase then a singular word

Comment: So please edit your question and add more information as to what you are referring to.

Comment: Too broad, also opinion based to an extent, open ended Q.

Comment: The elephant in the room is that *all in one* is only used attributively, while you are trying to use it predicatively. The result is ungrammatical. Some of the alternatives in the answer silently fix that, but only some, and only silently. And the larger context of the sample sentence is still not clear, so neither is it clear which of the options actually are options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous idiomatic phrases that suggest *all in one*, such as

> - the whole ball of wax
> - the whole shebang
> - one stop shopping
> - lock, stock, and barrel
> - all that and a bag of chips
> - from A to Z

Comment: *numerous idiomatic phrases* makes the Q. off-topic.

Comment: @Kris Not sure I disagree.

Comment: Did you mean to use a comma before *I disagree*? :)

Comment: @Kris Don't get telegraph speak? I do see the ambiguity. I meant *I'm not sure that I disagree with you*. You are probably right, but I couldn't resist seeing how many I could come up with in a few minutes.